# Grunt via atom won't work

Tags: gruntjs, atom-editor

I installed Atom editor and tried to run grunt task via plugin grunt-runner. But unsuccessfully. OS: windows 8.1

My steps were:

1) install node.js with npm

2) get grunt

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

3) install sass-plugin

```
npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev
```

4) create package.json file contained

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2"
  }
}
```

5) add Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {                              // Task
      dist: {                            // Target
        options: {                       // Target options
          style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: {                         // Dictionary of files
          'styles/main.css': 'styles/main.scss'       // 'destination': 'source'
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);
};
```

As a result on trying to launch grunt via Atom's grunt-runner plugin:

```
Grunt exited: code 1.
```

But if I execute it via terminal using "grunt"-command it works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't researched this issue completely but in my case it was some conflict between 'grunt-runner' and 'build' plugins for Atom.

Eventually, I just reinstall Atom without 'build' plugin and now it's works.
But I still have no idea why that conflict happened

Comment: I have the same problem, in terminal everything works like a charm but in grunt-runner i get: "Grunt exited: code 1." But in my case i dont have installed build-plugin. Any ideas?